# How to solve error : class java.io.BufferedInputStream cannot be cast to class javax.xml.transform.Result

Tags: java, xml, marshalling

I am trying to marshall (write) randomized TestReport objects into an xml file. It has only one field a list of : TestExecutions (which also has as fields Date dateTime & a list of another class objects)

```
public class JAXB {

   public static void marshall() {
        try {
            List<TestResult> testResultList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

                testResultList.add(i, new TestResult(Reporting.randomTestResultName(), TestStatus.randomEnumTestStatus()));

            }

            testResultList.sort((trl1, trl2) -> Reporting.compareNatural(trl1.getTestName(), trl2.getTestName()));

            TestExecution testExecution1 = new TestExecution(testResultList);
            List<TestExecution> testExecutionList = new ArrayList<>();
            testExecutionList.add(testExecution1);
            
            TestReport testReport2 = new TestReport(testExecutionList);
            
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestReport.class);
            Marshaller ms = jc.createMarshaller();
            ms.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            ms.marshal(testReport2, (javax.xml.transform.Result) System.in);
            ms.marshal(testReport2, new File("src\\data\\test.xml"));
            
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and I get this error : class java.io.BufferedInputStream cannot be cast to class javax.xml.transform.Result (java.io.BufferedInputStream is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; javax.xml.transform.Result is in module java.xml of loader 'bootstrap')

Comment: If you want just to marshall into xml file then you don't need your first `ms.marshal(...)` (can simply comment it out) as it tries to write to `System.in` which is obviously NOT an xml-file

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48-hour delay before doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).